# Can we install a Safari plugin to folder other than "/Library/Internet-Plugins" folder on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, plugins, safari

When i install my Safari Plugin on "Library/Internet-Plugins" folder on Mac OSX, it becomes available to all browsers.

How can i avoid that?
Can i install plugin to some other location and direct Safari to that?
Or something similar to Chrome/Firefox extension folder.

On OSX Safari does not have any /Plugin folder in Application Support. But on Windows it has.

Please guide me what i am missing here.

Advance Thanks

regards
Parimal Das

Comment: I misread your questions as "all users". I deleted my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it not possible to load for specific browser.

How i solved this is by using different mime types for different browser.

Thanks 
Parimal Das